# Solving cos(x)/sin(x) towaord x

Tags: trigonometry

So I have the following equation:

$$ \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{3}{\sqrt3}$$

and when solving it for $x$ (in the range of $[0 - \pi]$ ), I know the solution is $x=\pi/6$.

However I don't understand how this is done. What steps do I need to take to find $x$ for this and similar equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**:

$$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \iff \frac{1}{\tan x} = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$

This should be more straightforward to solve

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can also write $$\tan(x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently
$$
\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.
$$
The tangent function is strictly increasing in $(-\pi,\pi)$ with image from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, hence the solution exists and is unique. $x=\pi/6$ is *the* solution.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\sqrt3}{3}$

$\tan x = \frac1{\sqrt3}$

$\tan x = \tan \frac{π}{6}$

$x = \frac{π}{6}$

> Or

$ \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac3{\sqrt3}$

$\cot x = \sqrt3$

$\cot x = \cot \frac{π}{6}$

$x = \frac{π}{6}$

Comment: As you already specifying range.